# Silverlight Dataform: "Save" and "Edit" buttons not showing up

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, dataform

I'm trying to make a data form in Silverlight 4. Perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

The class:

```
public class ExpenseInfoTest
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <local:ExpenseInfoTest x:Key="newExpense"/>

    <df:DataForm Height="218" 
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 Margin="13,368,0,0" 
                 Name="expenseDataForm" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                 Width="590" 
                 CurrentItem="{StaticResource newExpense}" />
```

What is displayed:
[image: Just the fields without the save and edit buttons]

I'd like the "Save" button. How can I get it to appear? Is something wrong in my XAML or data class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your xaml, add

```
CommandButtonsVisibility="All"
```

in your `DataForm` declaration.

If you wanted to, you could bind the `CommandButtonsVisibility` to lets say a combo box

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding CommandButtonsVisibility, ElementName=expenseDataForm, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0" >
```

and be able to control which command buttons are available based on the CB selection.

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is helpful:

```
expenseDataForm.CommandButtonsVisibility = DataFormCommandButtonsVisibility.All;
```